# How to determine a correct promoter sequence? (Bisulfite sequencing)

Tags: gene, ngs, methylation, homework, epigenetics

I'd like to ask you for help with an university assignment. First let me post the entire question:

> Design primers for bisulfite sequencing of the promoter of the ACE2
> gene in microbat  Myotis lucifugus (based on the annotation of the
> Broad Institute Myoluc2.0/myoLuc2). The gene is localized on the
> contig GL429816. As a transcription start, use the start of the ACE2
> transcript variant XM_023753670.1; once you find ACE2 in the UCSC
> genome browser .You will find it in NCBI RefSeq track

I don't want anyone to solve it for me but I do have a problem with one aspect. I am not clear on how to determine what is a valid promoter for this gene in microbat. I do know it is the upstream sequence however I am not clear on how to tell the number of upstream bases that are the actual promoter. I did find some sources for the actual promoter sequence determined by much smarter people than myself however those are for ACE in humans so I am afraid that it is not applicable in my case.

I'd like someone to point me in the right direction where I could find my answer would be enough.

Comment: Thank you I decided to use 900bp, just because that is the legnth the teacher used in of his lectures. I would like to select you comment as an answer, but it's not possible it seems.

Comment: Posted it as answer, not sure if a moving function exists, maybe if you are a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no fixed size. Ideally you would have something like histone ChIP-seq or ATAC-seq data to approximate the relevant upstream interval. Since this is not always possible most people go with -500bp. Others might have different suggestions though. Maybe matching known motifs of transcription factors that regulate that promoter to the upstream region can help approximating a better window. But as Sanger sequencing usually gives about 1kb of sequence I'd just take a 500bp to 1kb window and sequence that, fwd and rev primers for sequencing to have double confirmation.